# Enviar formulario a PHP

Tags: mysql

Siempre que lleno los campos, y corro el codigo, me aparece "conexion fallida", y no entiendo. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Soy nuevo en php.

```
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_usuarios");
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $contraseña=$_POST["contraseña"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $comentario=$_POST["comentario"];
$insertar ="INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, contraseña, email, comentario) VALUES ('$nombre','contraseña','$email','$comentario')";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if(!$resultado){
    echo"conexion fallida";
}else{
    echo"conexion excelente";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: a que te refieres que lleno los campos, cuales campos? podrías agregar tu código?

Comment: Tendrías que mostrar el código para ver el problema, sino sería como solucionar un error a ciegas.

Comment: O sea, agregue el codigo, pero no se por que no lo mostro.

Comment: Como recomendación te diría que utilizaras PDO para trabajar con la base de datos, ya que es mas genérico para cualquier tipo de base de datos.

Comment: a que te refieres con validaciones @Villatoro?

Comment: a nada xd ya la corregi

Answer (score 2):

Con la poca información que tenemos, te doy algunas sugerencias:

1 - Verifica que el nombre de tu base de datos sea: `bd_usuarios`.

2 - Verifica si tu usuario es `"root"` y no le has asignado contraseña.

3 - en esta línea te faltó el símbolo $ en contraseña: `$insertar ="INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, contraseña, email, comentario) VALUES ('$nombre','contraseña','$email','$comentario')";` (Además tienes caracteres especiales, cambia **contraseña** por **contrasena**.

PD: también verifica que tu tabla se llame prueba1

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto tu respuesta, solo cambia lo que necesites.

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test"); // cabia tus datos
    $id = "1";
    $nombre="Test 1";// Solo necesitas cambiar tus variables
    //con las que necesites

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO test(IDTest, Texto1) VALUES ('$id','$nombre')") 
        or die('error: '.mysqli_error($conexion));

if(!$resultado){
    echo"<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissable'>Error de Conexion!</div>";
}else{
    echo"<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>Conexion Exitosa!</div>";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Te comento, si queres borras la parte de la sentencia if o la de error de mysql ambas hacen lo mismo